# How could a heart attack be prevented if a cholesterol buildup in an artery near the heart was detected?

Tags: prevention, heart-attack, blood-clotting

I learned that blood clots in coronary arteries caused by plaque ruptures are the most common cause of heart attacks, and this raised the question: If a severe cholesterol buildup were detected, how could it be removed to prevent a potentially fatal heart attack?

Comment: You may want to search for balloon angioplasty...then we can discuss further...

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?